# Simple Addition using sapply in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use sapply to add 0.84 until 1.7 is reached, so that I can avoid using a for loop.

What I already have tried:

```
my_vector2 <- sapply(-2.5:1.7, function(x) x + 0.84)
```

I am expecting to see `-1.66, -0.82, 0.02, 0.86, 1.7` but the output is `-1.66 -0.66  0.34  1.34  2.34`.

What am I missing?

Comment: `seq(-2.5,1.7,by = .84)` ?

Comment: You don't need to use sapply for that, you can add a value to a vector. The problem is in the intervals. What values are you hoping for with -2.5:1.7?

Comment: You are adding `0.84` to the following vector: `-2.5 -1.5 -0.5  0.5  1.5`. I guess the question is what do you expect -2.5:1.7 to produce?

Answer (score 2):

`seq()` can do what you want:

```
> seq(-2.5,1.7,by = .84)[-1]
[1] -1.66 -0.82  0.02  0.86  1.70
```

The point of the `[-1]` is to throw away the first number, `-2.5`. With round-off error, you might need to be careful with the final number as well. Type `?seq` at the prompt for additional information.